# Ruby array subtraction without removing items more than once

Tags: ruby, arrays

The canonical Array difference example in Ruby is:

```
[ 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5 ] - [ 1, 2, 4 ]  #=>  [ 3, 3, 5 ]
```

What's the best way to get the following behavior instead?

```
[ 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5 ].subtract_once([ 1, 2, 4 ])  #=>  [ 1, 2, 3, 3, 5 ]
```

That is, only the first instance of each matching item in the second array is removed from the first array.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Subtract values as many times as they appear in the other array, or any [Enumerable](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Enumerable.html):

```
class Array
  # Subtract each passed value once:
  #   %w(1 2 3 1).subtract_once %w(1 1 2) # => ["3"]
  #   [ 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5 ].subtract_once([ 1, 2, 4 ]) => [1, 2, 3, 3, 5]
  # Time complexity of O(n + m)
  def subtract_once(values)
    counts = values.inject(Hash.new(0)) { |h, v| h[v] += 1; h }
    reject { |e| counts[e] -= 1 unless counts[e].zero? }
  end
```

Subtract each *unique* value once:

```
require 'set'
class Array
  # Subtract each unique value once:
  #   %w(1 2 2).subtract_once_uniq %w(1 2 2) # => [2]
  # Time complexity of O((n + m) * log m)
  def subtract_once_uniq(values)
    # note that set is implemented 
    values_set = Set.new values.to_a 
    reject { |e| values_set.delete(e) if values_set.include?(e) }
  end
end
```

Comment: I'm going to accept this but it would be nice if the argument could contain duplicate values which get applied in turn (they get squashed by the conversion to Set). Not sure how you can keep the duplicates while still keeping performance. (Also I wanted to accept an array and not values as separate arguments, but that's an easy change)

Comment: I've updated the answer with a version that applies dupes as many times as they are present in the other array.

Comment: @glebm brilliant solution man! This really helped me a lot. You wrote this just to answer this SO question? Thanks a bunch.

Comment: @affinities23 You are welcome, Happy New Year! I wrote this to practice, was starting out with ruby back then :)

Answer (score 10):

```
class Array
  def subtract_once(b)
    h = b.inject({}) {|memo, v|
      memo[v] ||= 0; memo[v] += 1; memo
    }
    reject { |e| h.include?(e) && (h[e] -= 1) >= 0 }
  end
end
```

I believe this does what I want. Many thanks to @glebm

Comment: Suggestions: Inside of inject: `memo[v] ||= 0; memo[v] += 1; memo`
Inside of reject:
`h.include?(e) && !(h[e] -= 1).zero?`

Answer (score 8):

This is all I can think of so far:

```
[1, 2, 4].each { |x| ary.delete_at ary.index(x) }
```

Comment: That might get a bit slow if `m` (the size of [1,2,4]) is big

Comment: This solution only works if every element of the [1,2,4] array is present in `ary`. Otherwise the index of the element is nil. Inside could be something like: `i = ary.index(x); ary.delete_at(i) if i`

Answer (score 1):

Similar to @Jeremy Ruten's answer but accounting for the fact that some elements may not be present:

```
# remove each element of y from x exactly once
def array_difference(x, y)
  ret = x.dup
  y.each do |element|
    if index = ret.index(element)
      ret.delete_at(index)
    end
  end
  ret
end
```

This answer also won't modify the original array as it operates, so:

```
x = [1,2,3]
y = [3,4,5]
z = array_difference(x, y) # => [1,2]
x == [1,2,3]               # => [1,2,3]
```