# Remove common elements from two arrays while keeping duplicates in Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, logic

Let's say I have two arrays:

```
a = [1,1,2,3,3,3,3] 
b = [1,2]
```

If I want to remove b from a, I would like the following result:

```
c = [1,3,3,3,3]
```

How can I do this so that if I don't know what a and b hold, the following will both evaluate to c:

```
a-b = |c| just as b-a=|c|
```

All logic operations in ruby seem to delete duplicate values in an array.

This seems complicated

```
def try()
  a = [1,1,2,3,3,3,3]
  b = [1,1,2,3,5]
  min = a.length < b.length ? a : b
  c = a & b
  x = []
  for i in 0..c.length-1
    x[i] = min.count(c[i])
  end 
  union=[]
  k = 0;
  for i in 0..c.length-1
    for j in 0..x[i]-1
      union[k]=c[i]
      k +=1
    end
  end
  return union
end
```

union = [1,1,2,3]
I guess this just seems like a lot to get something so simple back.

Comment: Please post code indicating what you have tried.

Comment: How would `a-b` and `b-a` ever both be equal to `|c|`?  In the one case you end up with `[1,3,3,3,3]` in the other you end up with `[]` so they are not equal and the use of absolute value is meaningless, or used incorrectly.

Comment: What the result for `[1, 2] - [2, 3]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a = [1,1,2,3,3,3,3]
b = [1,2]

a.each_with_index {|av,ai|
  b.each_with_index {|bv,bi|
    if (av == bv)
      a[ai] = nil
      b.delete_at(bi)
      break
    end
  }
}

# a.compact!: [1,3,3,3,3]
```

For something a little more robust, see this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/3852809/183181

Or here if order is important:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/21737172/183181

Comment: I didn't know about each_with_index. Thanks. I've added what i wrote to solve this above in the question. Although, you can see it's a lot more than anyone would want to write.

Comment: I still find it strange that a & b doesn't give back a true union of elements (with all instances included) and instead only provides a list of the name of overlapping elements

Comment: `a = [1, 2, 3]`, `b = [1, 2]`, this results in `[2, 3]`. Do not remove elements inside an iteration.

Comment: @ArieShaw You are correct, I adjusted to make it similar to the original.  There's no threat in deleting from the internal, it would even optimize the lookup.  Without a more elaborate `throw`/`catch`, it's not as easy to redo nested loops in Ruby (something Perl handles with ease).  Of course there are multiple ways to do this, but this is quick-and-dirty answer help ;)

Comment: @ingrid, yes it would be nice if there was a union_preserve function or operator, which wouldn't reduce the array to a unique set of values; though, I'm not sure how common a task that is.  The link in the answer will probably lead you to something more worthwhile.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it this way:

```
a = [1,1,2,3,3,3,3]
b = [1,2]

b.each do |value_in_b|
  a.delete_at a.find_index(value_in_b)
end

p a #=> [1, 3, 3, 3, 3]
```

Comment: No, my method assumes that all values in b are in a, if that is not always the case one more statement needs to be added.