# Subtract arrays with frequency

Tags: arrays, ruby

I'm trying to subtract an array from another array taking frequency into account, like this:

```
[1,2,2,2] some_code [1,2] # => [2,2]
```

What's the easiest way to accomplish this?

Using `-` removes all occurrences of the elements in the second array:

```
[1,2,2,2] - [1,2] # => []
```

Comment: Does the order matter?

Comment: can you show your code please?

Comment: see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3852755/ruby-array-subtraction-without-removing-items-more-than-once

Comment: @sawa, no the order doesn't matter

Comment: I recently proposed that such a method, which I named `Array#difference`, be [added to the Ruby Core](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/11815#change-55656). Links to SO questions where I've used in can be found it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24987054/how-to-select-unique-elements).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a1 = [1,2,2,2]
a2 = [1,2]    
a2.each { |e| (idx = a1.find_index e) && (a1.delete_at idx) }
#⇒ [2, 2]
```

Here we iterate the second array and delete elements from the first one, once per iteration, if those were found.

The first found element will be deleted.

Comment: will throw error if `a2` contains an element which is not present in `a1`.

Comment: @shivam Indeed, thx, fixed.

Comment: Very nicely done! This does mutate `a1`, which I don't think you should do as it's not explicity permitted by the question. The obvious fix is merely to operate on `a1.dup`.

Answer (score 1):

```
a = [1, 2, 2, 2]
b = [1, 2]

ha = a.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)){|e, h| h[e] += 1}
# => {1=>1, 2=>3}
hb = b.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)){|e, h| h[e] += 1}
# => {1=>1, 2=>1}
(ha.keys | hb.keys).flat_map{|k| Array.new([ha[k] - hb[k], 0].max, k)}
# => [2, 2]
```

Comment: @CarySwoveland Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the problem correctly, that you wish to delete single occurrence of each element of array `b` from array `a`, here is one way to do this:

```
a.keep_if {|i| !b.delete(i)}
#=> [2,2]
```

PS: Both arrays `a` and `b` are mutated by above code, so you may want to use `dup` to create a copy if you want to retain original arrays.

Comment: If `a = [1,1]` and `b = [1,1]` I understand the OP wants an empty array returned (remove one `1` in `a` for each `1` in `b`), but `a.keep_if {|i| !b.delete(i)} #=> [1]` (because `delete(i)` deletes all instances of `i`).

Comment: Thanks @cary ... will work on update.

Answer (score -2):

```
def subtract arr_a, arr_b
  arr_b.each do |b| 
    idx = arr_a.index(b)
    arr_a.delete_at(idx) unless idx.nil?
  end
end
```

Output:

```
a = [1,2,2,2]
b = [1,2]
subtract a, b
puts "a: #{a}"
# => a: [2, 2]
```

Comment: No need of a duplicate answer.