# How to find count matching characters at the same indes and at an unmatching index

Tags: ruby, loops

I have built a version of mastermind that checks a user's input and provides feedback based on how close the user's guess was to the winning sequence. If you're not familiar with the game, you get feedback indicating how many of your characters were guessed correctly at the same index and how many characters guessed are in the sequence, but at the wrong index. If there are duplicates in the guess, then you would not count the extra values unless they correspond to the same number of duplicates in the secret code.

Example: If the sequence is ["G","G","G","Y"] and the user guesses ["G", "Y","G","G"] then you'd want to return 2 for items at the same index and 2 for items at different indexes that are included in the secret sequence.

Another example: If the sequence is ["X","R","Y","T"] and the user guesses ["T","T","Y","Y"] then you'd return 1 for items at the same index 1 for the character guessed that is in the sequence but at the wrong index.

Anyway, to me this is not a simple problem to solve. Here's the code I used to get it to work, but it's not elegant. There must be a better way. I was hoping someone can tell me what I'm missing here?? New to Ruby...

```html
def index_checker(input_array, sequence_array)
  count = 0
  leftover_input = []
  leftover_sequence = []

  input.each_with_index do |char, idx|
    if char == sequence[idx]
      count += 1
    else
      leftover_input << char
      leftover_sequence << sequence[idx]
    end
  end

diff_index_checker(leftover_input, leftover_sequence, count)
end

def diff_index_checker(input, sequence, count)
  count2 = 0
  already_counted = []

    input.each do |char|
      if sequence.include?(char) && !already_counted.include?(char)
        count2 += 1
        already_counted << char
      end
    end
[count, count2]
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a clean Ruby solution, written in idiomatic Ruby object-oriented style:

```
class Mastermind
  def initialize(input_array, sequence_array)
    @input_array = input_array
    @sequence_array = sequence_array
  end

  def matches
    [index_matches, other_matches]
  end

  def results
    [index_matches.size, other_matches.size]
  end

  private

  attr_reader :input_array, :sequence_array

  def index_matches
    input_array.select.with_index { |e, i| e == sequence_array[i] }
  end

  def other_matches
    non_exact_input & non_exact_sequence
  end

  def non_exact_input
    array_difference(input_array, index_matches)
  end

  def non_exact_sequence
    array_difference(sequence_array, index_matches)
  end

  # This method is based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/3852809/5961578
  def array_difference(array_1, array_2)
    counts = array_2.inject(Hash.new(0)) { |h, v| h[v] += 1; h }
    array_1.reject { |e| counts[e] -= 1 unless counts[e].zero? }
  end
end
```

You would use this class as follows:

```
>> input_array = ["G","G","G","Y"]
>> sequence_array = ["G", "Y","G","G"]
>> guess = Mastermind.new(input_array, sequence_array)
>> guess.results
#> [2, 2]
>> guess.matches
#> [["G", "G"], ["G", "Y"]]
```

Here's how it works. First everything goes into a class called Mastermind. We create a constructor for the class (which in Ruby is a method called `initialize`) and we have it accept two arguments: input array (the user guess), and sequence array (the answer).

We set each of these arguments to an instance variable, which is indicated by its beginning with `@`. Then we use `attr_reader` to create getter methods for `@input_array` and `@sequence_array`, which allows us to get the values by calling `input_array` and `sequence_array` from any instance method within the class.

We then define two public methods: `matches` (which returns an array of exact matches and an array of other matches (the ones that match but at the wrong index), and `results` (which returns a count of each of these two arrays).

Now, within the `private` portion of our class, we can define the guts of the logic. Each method has a specific job, and each is named to (hopefully) help a reader understand what it is doing.

`index_matches` returns a subset of the input_array whose elements match the sequence_array exactly.

`other_matches` returns a subset of the input_array whose elements do not match the sequence_array exactly, but do match at the wrong index.

`other_matches` relies on `non_exact_input` and `non_exact_sequence`, each of which is computed using the `array_difference` method, which I copied from another SO answer. (There is no convenient Ruby method that allows us to subtract one array from another without deleting duplicates).

Comment: That `inject` couldn't be replaced by `each_with_index` to avoid returning the memo object?, the `reject` for `each`?

Comment: @SebastianPalma Perhaps it could, but [per the comment line](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3852809/5961578), it's not even my code. I just needed a way to take the difference between two Arrays without losing the duplicates. However, note that this method needs to work regardless of index, so I can't think of an `each_with_index` solution off the top of my head.

Comment: I was especially interested in your reference to the 2010 SO answer that used `array_difference`. Though I had not seen that answer, a couple of years ago [I proposed that the same method be added to the Ruby core](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/11815). Curiously, we used the same name (`difference`) and implemented it in essentially the same way. There has been something less than a groundswell of support for my proposal, but I still think it would be a useful addition. Also, nice answer!

Comment: Thanks! This was super helpful.

Answer (score 1):

**Code**

```
def matches(hidden, guess)
  indices_wo_match = hidden.each_index.reject { |i| hidden[i] == guess[i] }
  hidden_counts = counting_hash(hidden.values_at *indices_wo_match)
  guess_counts = counting_hash(guess.values_at *indices_wo_match)
  [hidden.size - indices_wo_match.size, guess_counts.reduce(0) { |tot, (k, cnt)|
    tot + [hidden_counts[k], cnt].min }]
end

def counting_hash(arr)
  arr.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |s, h| h[s] += 1 }
end
```

**Examples**

```
matches ["G","G","G","Y"], ["G", "Y","G","G"]
  #=> [2, 2]
matches ["X","R","Y","T"] , ["T","T","Y","Y"]
  #=> [1, 1]
```

**Explanation**

The steps are as follows.

```
hidden = ["G","G","G","Y"]
guess = ["G", "Y","G","G"]
```

Save the indices `i` for which `hidden[i] != guess[i]`.

```
indices_wo_match = hidden.each_index.reject { |i| hidden[i] == guess[i] }
  #=> [1, 3]
```

Note that the number of indices for which the values are equal is as follows.

```
hidden.size - indices_wo_match.size
  #=> 2
```

Now compute the numbers of remaining elements of `guess` that pair with one of the remaining values of `hidden` by having the same value. Begin by counting the numbers of instances of each unique element of `hidden` and then do the same for `guess`.

```
hidden_counts = counting_hash(hidden.values_at *indices_wo_match)
  #=> {"G"=>1, "Y"=>1}
guess_counts = counting_hash(guess.values_at *indices_wo_match)
  #=> {"Y"=>1, "G"=>1}
```

To understand how `counting_hash` works, see [Hash::new](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Hash.html#method-c-new), especially the explanation of the effect of providing a *default value* as an argument of `new`. In brief, if a hash is defined `h = Hash.new(3)`, then if `h` does not have a key `k`, `h[k]` returns the default value, here `3` (the hash is not changed).

Now compute the numbers of matches of elements of `guess` that were not equal to the value of `hidden` at the same index and which pair with an element of `hidden` that have the same value.

```
val_matches = guess_counts.reduce(0) do |tot, (k, cnt)|
  tot + [hidden_counts[k], cnt].min
end
  #=> 2
```

Lastly, return the values of interest.

```
[hidden.size - indices_wo_match.size, val_matches]
  #=> [2, 2]
```

In the code presented above I have substituted out the variable `val_matches`.

With Ruby 2.4+ one can use [Enumerable#sum](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-sum) to replace

```
guess_counts.reduce(0) { |tot, (k, cnt)| tot + [hidden_counts[k], cnt].min }
```

with

```
guess_counts.sum { |k, cnt| [hidden_counts[k], cnt].min }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def judge(secret, guess)
  full = secret.zip(guess).count { |s, g| s == g }
  semi = secret.uniq.sum { |s| [secret.count(s), guess.count(s)].min } - full
  [full, semi]
end
```

Demo:

```
> judge(["G","G","G","Y"], ["G","Y","G","G"])
=> [2, 2]
> judge(["X","R","Y","T"], ["T","T","Y","Y"])
=> [1, 1]
```

A shorter alternative, though I find it less clear:

```
  full = secret.zip(guess).count(&:uniq!)
```

Comment: That’s nice and short but it’s relatively inefficient due to the repeated use of `count`, as compared with methods that determine all counts in a single pass.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I disagree. I just tried it, judging both examples a million times. My solution took 5.9 seconds, yours took 8.1 seconds with reduce and 9.1 seconds with sum.

Comment: One thing I do like (which I should have done) is to first calculate `full` and then subtract `full` from the second calculation, as it simplifies the second calculation.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Tried moveson's solution as well now, took 15.1 seconds.

Comment: Executing `count` repeatedly is O(n^2) whereas using a counting hash or `group_by` is close to O(n). I’m not surprised that `count` would win out with 4-element arrays with lots of dups. Try benchmarking with larger arrays with fewer dups.

Comment: @CarySwoveland With "larger" I guess you mean n=5? At least that's the largest of the 18 (!) variations that [Wikipedia's article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mastermind_(board_game)#Variations) lists (not counting the one with n=6 because it's judged differently).

Comment: I was addressing the problem in general, for arbitrarily-large arrays, thinking that would be of greatest interest and utility to readers who may have the same problem, but one that is unrelated to Mastermind.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Mmh... I'd say this judging method is pretty Mastermind-specific. At least I think I've encountered this several times for Mastermind but never for something else. But ok, added an answer that's almost as simple and that's efficient for the generalized task.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer my other answer for its simplicity, but this one would be faster if someone wanted to use this for arrays larger than Mastermind's.

```
def judge(secret, guess)
  full = secret.zip(guess).count { |s, g| s == g }
  pool = secret.group_by(&:itself)
  [full, guess.count { |g| pool[g]&.pop } - full]
end
```

Demo:

```
> judge(["G","G","G","Y"], ["G","Y","G","G"])
=> [2, 2]
> judge(["X","R","Y","T"], ["T","T","Y","Y"])
=> [1, 1]
```